Stop redirecting to another page in spring mvc post
I have a Spring MVC controller like this (with Spring 5.X version in case needed) for displaying and processing a form as shown below:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/map")
public class LocalMapController {
     
    // display the form
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list() {
 
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("map");
        mav.addObject("LocalMapForm", new LocalMapForm());
 
        return mav;
    }
 
    // process the form
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView process(ModelAndView mav,
            @ModelAttribute("LocalMapForm") LocalMapForm lmForm, BindingResult result)
            throws Exception {
         
     
         
        mav.setViewName("map");
        //mav.setViewName("message");
        //mav.addObject("successMsg", "Saved");
        return mav;
 
    }
 
}

map.jsp is where I have the form code defined and that's hitting this controller when submit button is clicked. So when I have the following lines in place in the POST method:
//mav.setViewName("map");
    mav.setViewName("message");
    mav.addObject("successMsg", "Saved");

After reaching the POST method, it get's redirected to message view ( I have message.jsp defined which contains <div class="message">${successMsg}</div> ) with a message "Saved".
Now, I don't want to redirect to another page as above and keep it to map page only where the form is present. Am I doing correct in the code shared above where I have the following defined?
mav.setViewName("map");
       //mav.setViewName("message");
       //mav.addObject("successMsg", "Saved");
       return mav;

Should it stay on the same page after the submit button is clicked? Or is it a good idea to have a separate controller for handling it as an Ajax request and keep the above controller just for displaying the form purposes?
